# looping in R for a specific column

Tags: r, loops

I am pretty new to programming. I am using R to loop through a data frame. In this instance I want to loop through column grp.

[image]

So for eval  take items (B3J and B3C) and add test number 1&2
for eval_1 take items (B3D and B32) and add test number 3&4
for eval_2 take items (B34 and B3E) and add test number 5&6
for control take items (B3H and B3A) and add test number 21&22
for control_1 take items (B30 and B3U) and add test number 23&24
for control_2 take items (B3Y and B3O) and add test number 25&26

I would like to know what is the best way to proceed

Thanks

Comment: `dplyr::count(df, grp, wt = 'test number')` where `df` is your data frame.

Comment: Maybe: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(gap) %>% summarize(sum("test number"))`

Comment: I know this is not the kind of comment you'll like, but R is not a DBMS in the first place. Do you really need R here ? You can always use the `for` loop in last resort.

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to provide a minimal reproducible dataset for us to work with. One way is by using `dput`. You can see how to use this command in the following video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg